# Using shell script to sort files then delete old files

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I have a folder with some normal files.  I want to sort them by their modified date, keeps the latest 20 entries, and from what's left, erases anything older than 20 days.

Here is my code to delete files those are > 20 days.

```
#!/bin/bash
cleanup="../some path/"

find $cleanup/*gz -mtime +20 -exec rm {} \;
```

However, I don't know how to keep the last modified 20 files, then doing the delete. How to fix it please?

Comment: you should probably use `find "$cleanup" -name "*.gz"` so that bash wouldn't use `*` expansion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can filter 20 filenames out with

```
awk 'NR > 20'
```

Full command:

```
find ...... | awk 'NR > 20' | xargs -r  rm
```

For example

```
seq 30 | xargs -i echo 'file{}' | awk 'NR > 20' | xargs  -r rm
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. So in my example, where should I put the "|awk 'NR>20'| please?   I am a little bit confuse.

Comment: I haven't checked but this should work '`find $cleanup/*gz -mtime +20 | awk 'NR > 20' | xargs -r  rm`